# Cannot see cufon powered H3 in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, cufon

I cannot see cufon powered H3 tags in IE9 [here](http://www.pctips3000.com)

All other browsers including IE8 are fine. Anybody can tell me how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the cufon script works with IE9.  Make sure you have v1.09i or higher installed.

Download from:
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Supporting documentation about this issue:
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq#wiki-faq-1